# Post padding-top in mobile too large

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I created my website using Bootstrap and then converted it to WordPress:  [My website](http://rezeswebdev.com). I'm not new to Bootstrap, but am new to WordPress.

I'm having a problem that I just can't solve: When I look at the blog page or any of the posts pages in mobile view, there's a huge padding at the top of the post header.

I've tried modifying my CSS file to reduce padding at the top of the heading:

```
.entry-header {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

but it's just not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your padding but with your `#sidebar` div. The sidebars height is causing the mobile issue.

As you are hiding all of the content in your sidebar you might as well hide the whole sidebar on mobile using a media query.

Add this toward the bottom of your css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #sidebar {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  I didn't even think that the issue would be the sidebar- I was focusing on the padding.